# How to remove boxing using Code Clean up in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-cleanup, boxing, unboxing

There is a feature in Intellij Idea called **Analyze > Code Cleanup**. This cleans up the code (like removes unnecessary instances of *this.*). I am editing a very old script in a newer version of Java. I'm in a file, and there is almost 700 warnings saying **Remove Boxing** and **Remove Unboxing**. For some reason, when I run code cleanup, it cleans up everything except this. The severity in my settings for this is at *warning*. What can I do to automatically remove all unnecessary *Boxing* and *Unboxing* from this old script?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does it work if you use "run inspection by name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way if you have one file (or only a few):

- hover over one line having warning till a quick fix pop up appears and click on **More actions...**

[image]

- click on the arrow **>**

[image]

- choose **fix all 'Unnecessary unboxing' problems in file**

[image]

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much

Comment: @DayTrip You are welcome. Happy to help.